# "'str' object is not callable" using DictVectorizer on a column of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, feature-extraction, dictvectorizer

I'm developing a machine learning project in which I need to predict the prices of hotel rooms.

Since in my data set there are also the names of the hotels, I want to improve the performance of my model by using `DictVectorizer` on the name feature.

However Python keeps presenting the `"str' object is not callable"`  error at the line `vec= dict.fit_transform(X_data)`. Can anyone help me with this?

[The code is in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGfsY.png)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I think the issue arises due to use of `dtype='str'` while initializing `DictVectorizer(sparse=False,dtype='str')`. Instead it should be specified as `dtype=str` without the quotes. `str` is not a callable object in python whereas `str` is a callable object.

Comment: its late but mark answer as accepted if it worked. Thanks.